# How does ActiveState's PPM generate HTML and where does it store it?

Tags: perl, activestate

I'm using ActiveState Perl 5.22.3 currently and have that installed system wide, while I want to install additional packages using PPM per user only. This works after setting `PERL5LIB` e.g. to the path `C:/Users/[...]/AppData/Roaming/Perl/x64/Current/lib` and selecting that directory in the GUI of PPM as the target for installations. What doesn't seem to work is generation of HTML documentation from the installed packages.

The system wide installation folder of Perl contains a `html` directory with lots of docs with what got installed by default and using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) I can see that PPM tries to delete the file `perltoc.html` from that folder. After giving my user permissions to change contents of that directory, that file is recreated, but it doesn't contain any hints to newly installed packages of PPM. Without changing permissions, PPM logs the following error:

> 2020-02-03T18:57:54 <4> [ppm.bat:26] Can't open 'C:\Program Files\Perl\Current\html/perltoc.html': Permission denied at C:/Program Files/Perl/Current/lib/ActivePerl/DocTools.pm line 36.

That's why I thought that PPM might simply stop too early and doesn't provide HTML successfully. But things doesn't seem to be so easy and there's another HTML-folder in my user profile containing directories for all installed packages already:

```
C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Roaming\Perl\x64\5.22.3\html\site\lib
```

The problem is that this thing doesn't contain any files. Looking at Process Monitor, I'm not even sure if PPM generates HTML files at all, even though my packages contain POD-files: PPM is working in temporary directories for each package to install and those contain `html`-folders and PPM iterates the contents of those, but they seem to be empty. Process Monitor doesn't log any found files and PPM doesn't attempt to copy any individual file at all, even though it logs a copy process:

```
[InstallArea.pm:362] Installing AAAAAAAAA with id 91
[InstallArea.pm:369] Copy C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\ppm-eYtrkD/AAAAAAAAA-1.01/blib/html --> C:/Users/[...]/AppData/Roaming/Perl/x64/Current/html
[InstallArea.pm:369] Copy C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\ppm-eYtrkD/AAAAAAAAA-1.01/blib/lib --> C:/Users/[...]/AppData/Roaming/Perl/x64/Current/lib
```

So, how should PPM work regarding HTML-docs at all? How does it decide when to generate that, where does it generate that and where does it put it? I couldn't find much docs about how things should work by default.

Thanks!

Comment: `ActiveState::DocTools::Tree::HTML::Update_blib` seems to be the right track and it seems replacing `perltoc.html` is the last thing done. Though I can't see HTML files of new packages and don't know which of those packages should result in individual HTML files at all. POD-files are copied and HTML is generated for installed packages always, so it might be that my installed packages simply don't provide any additional HTML? Debugging is difficult: `ActivePerl::DocTools::UpdateHTML_blib(verbose => 0, blib => "$pname/blib");`